# Eureka how to set locale to DateInlineRow's DatePicker without setting tintColor

Tags: eureka-forms

I'm using Eureka for new iOS App. I found how to set the locale of date picker which is in inline row. But I don't know it is the best way.

I tried this:

```
DateInlineRow() {
            $0.title = "Birthday"
            $0.onExpandInlineRow{ (cell, row, pickerRow) in
                pickerRow.cell.datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
            }
        }
```

it works. But this code overwrites default onExpandInlineRow's callback, so the tintColor is not work.

workaround:

```
DateInlineRow() {
            $0.title = "Birthday"
            var defaultTextColor: UIColor? = nil
            $0.onExpandInlineRow{ (cell, row, pickerRow) in
                pickerRow.cell.datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
                defaultTextColor = cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor
                cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .mint
            }
            $0.onCollapseInlineRow{ (cell, row, pickerRow) in
                cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = defaultTextColor
            }
        }
```

I'd like to change only the locale without setting tintColor. But I have to set tintColor.